# show and hide div change position depending on the order its corresponding buttons are clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, show-hide

I appreciate if anyone could help (I am fairly new to code so pardon the syntax).

But what I am looking is for two buttons (button A and button B) to hide and show its corresponding divs (div A and div B) which operate individually. The divs will appear taking up 50% of screen width and depending on the order they are clicked will determine their position. First click (regardless if its button A or button B) will appear 50% width right of screen and second click (again regardless if button A or button B) will appear 50% width left of screen.

[image: diagram to illustrate problem]

I was able to create a show and hide div but wouldn't know how to determine their position depending on the order their corresponding buttons are clicked...

Comment: There is no syntax to pardon because there is no code. Unless you are referring to English syntax...

Comment: yar my explanation syntax.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I associated both buttons with a class, so I could query the buttons together. Then I made a data-id to reference each button / div. Then I queried both buttons and added a click event. Grabbing the data-id to differentiate the buttons, then I queried the columns. if the data-id's match then I display the div and display it after the next button pressed, so whichever button you press will be first. Then I added a class called show to differentiate whether or not it was showing, like a toggle. If the toggle class is show, I hide it, otherwise I show it / remove the class toggle. If the buttons don't match by data-id, then I put it before the other div, to make sure the div is always before the other when clicked in sequence.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            .columns{
                width:50%;
                height:100%;
            }
            body , html{
                height:100%;
            }
            span{
                margin-top:50%; margin-bottom:50%;
            }
            .columns div{
                position:relative;
                top:50%;
                color:white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="buttons" data-id="buttonA">Button A</button>
        <button class="buttons" data-id="buttonB">Button B</button>
    
    <div style="height:50%; display:flex;">
        <div class="columns" data-id="buttonA" style="background-color:green; text-align:center; position:relative; display:none;">
    <div>div a</div>
        </div>
        <div class="columns" data-id="buttonB" style="background-color:red; text-align:center; position:relative; display:none;">
    <div>div b</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        let buttons=document.querySelectorAll('.buttons')
        for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            
        
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click',function (params) {
    
            let button = params.target.getAttribute('data-id');
            let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.columns');
            for (let index = 0; index < divs.length; index++) {
                
                if (button==divs[index].getAttribute('data-id')){
                    divs[index].style.display="Block"
                    divs[index].after(divs[divs.length-1])
                    if (divs[index].classList.contains('show')){
                    divs[index].classList.remove('class','show');
                    divs[index].style.display = "none"
                    }
                    else{
                    divs[index].classList.add('show')
                    divs[index].style.display="Block"
                    }
                }else {
                    divs[index].before(divs[divs.length-1])
                }
                
                
            }
        })
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Code should always be accompanied by more explanation than "Try this" or "Here is my solution." You should be telling people who visit this question why your answer is worthy of an upvote. Typically this is done by showing you know how to code and didn't just copy and paste the answer from an LLM...

Comment: Answers consisting of only code are not very helpful. Please explain what this code does and how it answers the question. Also, keep in mind that your answer is not only for the OP; it's for anyone else who may find this question (and subsequently your answer) in the future. Explaining your code helps people recognize if the code fits their situation and tells them if it may need to be modified to fit their situation without having to read through and decipher the code itself, which is a waste of their time. See [how to answer](/help/how-to-answer) for more info on how to improve your answer.

Comment: Thank you Zachary this is awesome is there any possibility that after first click (from either button A or B) that is corresponding div will appear right of screen and the button div thereafter to appear left. Rather than second click moving the div to the right?

Comment: I’ll go more into detail, sorry I was in a rush. I was just getting out of work.